# Is there a way of finding the closest colour from collection of colours in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, colors, compare

My collection is looking like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5817b3f6980433b0ccae6376"),
    "name": "Test",
    "colours" : [ 
        {
            "name":"Test color1",
            "colourRgb":[22,222,111]
        },
        {
            "name":"Test color6",
            "colourRgb":[222,212,92]
        }
        ...
    ],
    "__v" : 13
}
```

Where the colours can vary from 100 to 1 000 000.

I have the formula to compare to colours:

```
let color1 = [255,255,255];
let color2 = [255,255,255];
let diff = (Math.abs(color1[0] - color2[0]) + Math.abs(color1[1] - color2[1]) + Math.abs(color1[2] - color2[2]))/3
console.log(diff);
```

But how can I use it with mongoDB to find the closest colour.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To compare colors for "closeness," you should first convert the RGB to XYZ, a linear system of 3 variables X, Y, and Z that describes all visible colors. Then convert that to L*a*b* (aka Lab) which represents colors as a combination of lightness (L*) and hue and saturation (a* and b*). L*a*b* is more perceptually uniform than either RGB or XYZ. From there the perceptual closeness of colors is measured by various flavors of Delta E, the most common one used is Delta E 1976. See the math tab on this site for the formulas http://www.brucelindbloom.com/